# How do I detect the version of find on OSX

Tags: mac-osx, shell, find

I need to detect which version of the find command is used from a shell script. GNU find supports the `--version` argument but the find command on OSX apparently does not support that. Is there a way to detect which version it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ strings `which find`|grep find.c
```

sorry, can't find a nicer way than that. but I believe you should just check the OS version, not the individual program.

Comment: very creative :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. Since you didn't explain more about why you need it, I can only suggest at this point that it would be wise to just use the features of find that are specified by the POSIX standard. It's easy to distinguish GNU find vs BSD find (the one that comes with MacOS X) by just trying the --version parameter.